# Django + Celery + Redis

Tags: python, django, redis, celery

I have this settings in my social_media.settings:

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = "redis://0.0.0.0:6379/0"
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ["application/json"]
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = "json"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis://0.0.0.0:6379/0"
CELERY_TIMEZONE = "Europe/Kiev"
```

Also I register in my social_media.**init**:

```
from .celery import app as celery_app


__all__ = ("celery_app", )
```

Also I have this celery.py file:

```
import os

from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "social_media.settings")


app = Celery("social_media")
app.config_from_object("django.conf:settings", namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()
```

And I run redis with docker command:

```
docker run -d -p 6379:6379 redis
```

So after I run my django project and my docker, I want to run celery with this command:

```
celery -A social_media worker -l info
```

I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "D:\projects\social-media-api\venv\Scripts\celery.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\__main__.py", line 15, in main
sys.exit(_main())
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\celery.py", line 236, in 
main
return celery(auto_envvar_prefix="CELERY")
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1157, in 
__call__
return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1078, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1688, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1434, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 783, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 33, in 
new_func
return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\base.py", line 134, in 
caller
return f(ctx, *args, **kwargs)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\bin\worker.py", line 348, in 
worker
worker = app.Worker(
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 98, in 
__init__
self.setup_instance(**self.prepare_args(**kwargs))
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\worker\worker.py", line 119, 
in setup_instance
self._conninfo = self.app.connection_for_read()
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 818, in 
connection_for_read
return self._connection(url or self.conf.broker_read_url, **kwargs)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\celery\app\base.py", line 877, in 
_connection
return self.amqp.Connection(
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\connection.py", line 201, in 
__init__
if not get_transport_cls(transport).can_parse_url:
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\__init__.py", line 
90, in get_transport_cls
_transport_cache[transport] = resolve_transport(transport)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\__init__.py", line 
75, in resolve_transport
return symbol_by_name(transport)
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\utils\imports.py", line 59, in 
symbol_by_name
module = imp(module_name, package=package, **kwargs)
File "C:\Python39\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
File "d:\projects\social-media-api\venv\lib\site-packages\kombu\transport\redis.py", line 266, 
in <module>
class PrefixedStrictRedis(GlobalKeyPrefixMixin, redis.Redis):
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'Redis'
```

how can i fix this because as i understand celery should connect to my container with path 0.0.0.0:6379 but instead of this i have this error

Comment: upd: i forgot to install redis locally